# Apache Ambari - Registration Failed (HostnotFound Exception)

Tags: apache, ambari

I am trying to create a Cluster of Nodes using Apache Ambari. During the steps, in step 3 we need to give the list of hosts to be added to the cluster using the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name)

To get the FQDN, I used

```
$ hostname -f
```

Commmand in Ubuntu Terminal. Got the Result as sridhar25

During the Cluster Creation gave my FQDN as sridhar25 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IYCq.png

But after selecting Next, I am getting Registration Failed.

```
Registering with the Server.....
Registration with the Server Failed
```

My Log File shows

```
04 Mar 2016 11:05:05,268 ERROR [qtp-client-25] AbstractResourceProvider:280 - Caught AmbariException when creating a resource
org.apache.ambari.server.HostNotFoundException: Host not found, hostname=sridhar25
at org.apache.ambari.server.state.cluster.ClustersImpl.getHost(ClustersImpl.java:308)
at org.apache.ambari.server.state.ConfigHelper.getEffectiveDesiredTags(ConfigHelper.java:104)
at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariActionExecutionHelper.addExecutionCommandsToStage(AmbariActionExecutionHelper.java:342)
at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariManagementControllerImpl.createAction(AmbariManagementControllerImpl.java:2983)
at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.RequestResourceProvider$1.invoke(RequestResourceProvider.java:161)
at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.RequestResourceProvider$1.invoke(RequestResourceProvider.java:158)
at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.AbstractResourceProvider.createResources(AbstractResourceProvider.java:273)
at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.RequestResourceProvider.createResources(RequestResourceProvider.java:158)
at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.ClusterControllerImpl.createResources(ClusterControllerImpl.java:289)
at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.persistence.PersistenceManagerImpl.create(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:75)
at org.apache.ambari.server.api.handlers.CreateHandler.persist(CreateHandler.java:36)
at org.apache.ambari.server.api.handlers.BaseManagementHandler.handleRequest(BaseManagementHandler.java:72)
at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseRequest.process(BaseRequest.java:135)
at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseService.handleRequest(BaseService.java:103)
at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseService.handleRequest(BaseService.java:72)
at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.RequestService.createRequests(RequestService.java:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Even I tried by changing the FQDN to

```
$ hostname -f
sridhar25.sridhar.com
```

I am getting the Same errors

How to Register the hosts in the Ambari-Cluster?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a DNS issue. Did you add entries for all nodes to the /etc/hosts file on each node?

Run the following commands on each node to get the correct FQDN and IP respectively.

```
hostname -f
ifconfig
```

Once you have those values you need to add them to the /etc/hosts file on each host.

For example, if you only had two nodes and if you get values:

```
sridhar25:
sridhar25.sridhar.com
192.168.1.12

sridhar26:
sridhar26.sridhar.com
192.168.1.13
```

Then you would need to add the following two lines to each /etc/hosts file:

```
192.168.1.12 sridhar25.sridhar.com
192.168.1.13 sridhar26.sridhar.com
```

Comment: Yes, I have run the above commands, and entered appropriate details in /etc/hosts file. Yet the problem persists

Comment: My etc/hosts file has                                                                                            127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1 sridhar25.sridhar.com sridhar25

192.168.117.153 sridhar25.sridhar.com sridhar25
192.168.117.107 localhostcs1.sridhar.com localhostcs1 
192.168.117.140 localhostcs2.sridhar.com localhostcs2

Comment: That doesn't look correct. Try it after removing the following line:
127.0.1.1 sridhar25.sridhar.com sridhar25.